# Ask for some percolation reference textbook

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, textbook-recommendation, percolation

I try to learn Bernoulli percolation recently. Could anyone provide some lecture notes or textbooks to enter this field? Thanks.

Comment: [Introduction to Bernoulli percolation](http://www.ihes.fr/~duminil/publi/2017percolation.pdf) --- free to read; there is also this [introduction](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-34806-1_3) --- behind a paywall.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for your answer!